# how to access a json_decoded array with string keys/indizes via integer numbers

Tags: php, json, decode

json data looks like this:

```
{"name":{"id":55555555,"name":"name" ...}}
```

`echo $id[0]["id"];` returns

> Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index\lol\time.php on line 12

only `echo $id["name"]["id"];` returns the desired id.

The problem is that the "name" key is not static and will change every request, so how can i access the id?

Comment: Use `array_keys()`

Comment: if theres only ever going to be a single key present you might be able to use `array_values($id)[0]`.

Comment: Thanks guys, it works :)